# How to call action of struts2 from open method of ajax xmlhttp.open("GET", "action_name", true);

Tags: ajax, struts2

I want to get some data from action of struts2 and assign it to the object created in jsp file by using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Give it the URL to your Struts2 action. If you need to return JSON from your action, there is a plugin for that which comes bundled with Struts2.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a struts action is very easy just mention the action name as the url.In order to get some data from action and use it in your jsp take a look at [this link](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ajax.html)